# FloodFill using C#

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to rewrite some old vb6 code using C#. The problem is that when I used FloodFill in vb  it saves the image with the affect of  FloodFill. This is not true using C#. Here is the code segment for VB6:

```
hTempBrush = CreateSolidBrush(&H400000)   
'Select the brush into the dc.
hPrevBrush = SelectObject(Maparea.hdc, hTempBrush)
'Fill the area.
FloodFill Maparea.hdc, (100 ), (200), MapColor
SelectObject Maparea.hdc, hPrevBrush
DeleteObject hTempBrush
SavePicture Maparea.Picture, "filename.bmp" ' saves picture with flood fill affect
```

and here is the c#

```
Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.handle);
IntPtr vDC = g2.GetHdc();
IntPtr vBrush = CreateSolidBrush(ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Navy));
IntPtr vPreviouseBrush = SelectObject(vDC, vBrush);
int hh = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Wheat);
FloodFill(vDC, 100, 200, hh);
SelectObject(vDC, vPreviouseBrush);
DeleteObject(vBrush);
pictureBox1.Image.Save("map.bmp");  // saves without the affect of floodfill
g2.ReleaseHdc(vDC);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're using the hDC of a Control, then try to save the Bitmap assigned to its Image property. These two have nothing in common (except the Control itself). Use the hDC of the Bitmap and floodfill it. BTW, you should use [ExtFloodFill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-extfloodfill) (which is a really *intolerant* function - as its old version - and gives really bad results). Unless you don't care, you should try to do this *manually*, using the brightness of the Color that defines the area or border. Add a tolerance, to preserve anti-aliased areas.

Comment: You also have the option to draw the Image on the Control's surface - **in the Paint event of the Control** - use the Controls hDC for the `ExtFloodFill` function (`e.Graphics.GetHdc()`), call `e.Graphics.Flush()` before `[Control].DrawToBitmap()`. Of course you don't need to assign a Bitmap to the Image property.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the response. I tried flush then DrawToBitmap() and I got the same result. However during the search for DrawToBitmap, I found the answer to my question it's BitBlt.

Comment: `Control.DrawToBitmap()` **does use BitBlt**. But, as mentioned, you have to use the Graphics object provided by the PaintEventArgs object of the Paint event: it's the hDC reference that counts here. You were using the wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I have to use BitBlt so every thing appears on the control surface is saved.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    using (var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        var despDC = bmpGraphics.GetHdc();
        using (Graphics formGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle))
        {
            var srcDC = formGraphics.GetHdc();
            BitBlt(despDC, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, srcDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            formGraphics.ReleaseHdc(srcDC);
        }
        bmpGraphics.ReleaseHdc(despDC);
    }
    bmp.Save("map1.jpg");
```